# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor in Telegram-bot Java

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Im new to Java and trying to build a **Telegram** bot,that collects data from users.
The Process is that user sends a Text and to verify himself , he should send a picture after that. if he sends **no pic**, the process wont be complete. **but the data will be saved in my class**.
i used `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` to check after 5 Minutes whether something is stored in variable or not, if its true and  the bot didnt receive a pic, deletes the stored data.
but it didnt work. because it checks the variable on a regular base 5 Minutes, i want it to check the variable from the time, when user send his text(data stored in variable).
 could somebody suggest a better way or a solution to solve this?

my code looks like this:

Main Class:

```
public class MainClass {



        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ApiContextInitializer.init();
            TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();

            try {
                telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new StudiumBot());

            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


}
```

Bot Class:

```
    public class XXXBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {


        public static String answer = null;
        public static boolean photo_sent= false;


        public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {



           if (update.hasPhoto()) {


                photo_sent= true;

            }

         if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().getText().contains("XXXX")) {

                answer=update.getMessage().getText();

                ThreadPool.poolExecutor();

            }


        }
    }
```

ThreadPool Class:

```
    public class ThreadPool {
        public static void poolExecutor() {
            ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor stpe = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
            stpe.scheduleAtFixedRate(new VariableRemover(), 0, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        }
    }
```

The Class, that removes stored Data:

```
public class VariableRemover implements Runnable {

    public void run(){
        if(! XXXBot.photo_sent){
           XXXBot.answer= null;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of achieving that would be to maintain a timestamp in the XXXBot class.

```
public class XXXBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot{
    ....
    public static long timeWhenThisObjectWasBuilt = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

And then in the VariableRemover class check if the object should be deleted based on time check:

```
public class VariableRemover implements Runnable {
   private long expiryTime = 10*60*1000; // convert minutes to millis
   public void run(){
       if(! photo_sent && System.currentTimeMillis() > (timeWhenThisObjectWasBuilt + expiryTime)){
          answer= null;
       }

   }

}
```

Note: You cannot have two top level public classes in one file.